# How to convert inline babel script to JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, inline, babeljs

I am new to React JS and written some `React JS` code directly to `HTML` and it is working fine.

Now when I converted this inline code to JS using babel converter using [Online Babel Converter](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) and link the `Converted JS` to `HTML`, it is showng the blank the `UI` with no error or warning on browser console window.

I've written the inline babel script in `<script type="text/babel> ... </script>` tag

Note: I converted the inline code with default selected options in [Online Babel Converter](https://babeljs.io/en/repl), `Evaluate` in `Settings`, `stage-2` & `react` in `Presets`

> Edit: Added some portion of code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/babel>
            class App extends React.Component {
                createCircles = () => {
                let circles = [];
            
                for(let i = 1; i <= this.props.count; i++){
                    circles.push(<div className = "smallCircle" id={'circle'+i} key={i}><code className="circles" id={'id'+i}>{i}</code></div>);
                }
                                
                return circles;
            }
                        
                render(){
                    return (
                        <div id="circles">
                            <div className = "bigCircle" id="bigCircle">
                                <img id="bigCircleImage" src="http://localhost" />
                            </div>
                            <div className = "smallCircles">
                                {this.createCircles()}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                 }
            }
            
            function AppLoader(){
                return (
                    <App />
                );
            }
                        
            ReactDOM.render(<AppLoader />, document.getElementById('root'));
        </script>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean you've used online convertor as in you've posted each file into it and created a dist folder? or do you only have one file

Comment: All code in one file

Comment: it would help to see it

Comment: It's too big code, but I addeded some of the code here

Comment: well you havent got any imports?

Comment: why have you got appLoader why not just use <App/>

Comment: dont use an online compiler thats just for seeing what sort of code it spits out look at parcel.js very easy to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with @JoeWarner answer to not to use extra AppLoader function if you are not returning more than one component.

Coming to the question, I saw that you written the script before the div tag of id root. After converting your script, import the script below the  tag to see the changes